# Comparing not then and vs and then not

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I'm just wondering if there's a difference between an `if` or a `while` statement if the condition is either `(!a && !b)` (let's call this statement 1) or `!(a && b)` (let's call this statement 2).

I was thinking about it, and we have four combinations of a and b possible, and I think that the condition would be different if  `a != b`. I'm just hoping someone can check my logic.

If a and b are both true, then statements 1 and 2 are both false. If a and b are both false, then statements 1 and 2 are both true. ?However, if a is true and b is false, or the inverse, then statement 1 is false, but statement 2 is true. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually asking about a fundamental law of Boolean Algebra:  **De Morgan's Laws** are very useful to know when re-working or simplifying conditionals.

### De Morgan's Laws

```
!(a && b)  =  (!a || !b)
!(a || b)  =  (!a && !b)
```

Your intuition that your statements 1 and 2 might not be equivalent is correct.  Working through the four possibilities of `a` and `b` above shows that the actual equivalencies are those given by De Morgan's Laws.

[image]

**Key: ∧ is logical AND (&&); ∨ is logical OR (||).**

<sub>Image source: http://ndp.jct.ac.il/tutorials/mavomath/node15.html</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`!(a && b) = !a || !b` this does not equal `!a && !b`. In the first case if `a` or `b` is false then the result is true. In the second case both `a` and `b` must be false for the result to be true.

So as you say they have different results when `a != b`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was just looking for confirmation, and thanks for the alternate representation of statement 1.